# Cordova Build android - FAILURE: Build failed with an exception

Tags: cordova, onsen-ui

**Cordova Build Error**

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':CordovaLib'.

  > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':CordovaLib:classpath'.
  >   Could not find intellij-core.jar (com.android.tools.external.com-intellij:intellij-core:26.0.1).
  >    Searched in the following locations:
  >        https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/external/com-intellij/intellij-core/26.0.1/intellij-core-26.0.1.jar
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org